# Using object's setter to trigger data updates, best practices

Tags: domain-driven-design, setter

I have an object that gets instantiated in a linq to sql method. When the object fields are being assigned, i want to check a date field and if it is an old date, retrieve data from another table and perform calculations before continuing with assigning this object.
Is there anything wrong with triggering such an event through the property setter Or should I independently check the date through some service and make the changes if necessary at some point aftwewards?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with doing some logic from within your setters, but you should be careful about just how much logic you put within your setters.  One of the fundamental problems of setters is that since they act like attributes, but have backing code, it's easy to forget that there are potentially some non-trivial actions going on behind the scenes.

This sort of thing can cause problems if you have accessors which use accessors which use accessors; you can rapidly end up causing unexpected performance problems.  Generally, it's a good idea to keep the actions of setters (or getters, for that matter) to a relatively small set of actions.  For example, validation can work perfectly fine in a setter, but I'd generally advise against doing validation against external resources, because of two things: first, resource delays can cause problems with expected access speed, and secondly, the number of external resource accesses can destroy your performance.

Generally, the rule is this: keep it simple.  It's not unreasonable to do complicated things in a setter, but if you do, it's really important to understand the consequences of all of the actions you'll be causing, and it's EXTREMELY important to document what it does extremely well, so the next guy (or girl) to use the code doesn't just try to naively use the accessor and end up causing massive resource contention issues unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

Half the point of using setters instead of, say, public fields, is to be able to trigger events associated with setting certain data.

Keyword: associated. If you're just using the setter as a "convenient" time to do some other stuff because it happens to work, you're doing it wrong. If setting this value requires other work to be done, then by all means, use the setter to do it.